# How to use @ syntax in mvc in angularJS for isolate scope

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

In below code, when i running the application it is showing the error:

> Message:""'," is not valid at the start of a code block. Only
>   identifiers, keywords, comments, "(" and "{" are valid.

Within the scope due to `@` syntax .this is not working.
I am implementing this application in mvc and this code in on viewpage not in `.js` file.

@ syntax is treated here as Rajor due to which above error is generating..

```
var appmodule = angular.module('myapp', []);

appmodule.controller('myController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.name = "title1";

    //$scope.reverseName = function () {
    //    $scope.name = $scope.name.split('').reverse().join('');
    //};
});

appmodule.directive('myDir', function () {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: "<div>Your name is : {{name}}</div>"+
    "Change your name : <input type='text' ng-model='name' />"
        ,
        scope: {
            name: '@', // THIS LINE
        },
    }
});
```

Comment: I think you want to use '=' instead of '@' (2-way binding)

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the name of the attribute in camel case from where angular should bind the value

```
 scope: {
        name: '@thisIsALongName', // THIS LINE

    },
```

So in the HTML :

```
<my-dir this-is-a-long-name="{{user.lastname}}"></my-dir>
```

EDIT as said in comment : if you don't precise an attribute name `name:'@'` is the same than `name:'@name'`

Comment: This is not true. If you don't specify an attribute name, it just tries to bind to the same name as the variable, in this case 'name'